# removing http referer problem

Tags: python, django

I want to remove the http referer from the header while redirecting to other page. I am using python and django in the application. Is there a way to remove or reset the referer info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referer header is sent by the browser, so you can't control it from the server side.

Comment: As far as I know, the only option is to disable this header in your browser settings. But then again, you can not control the settings of your user's browser :)